# Error 324 empty response - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, django, nonetype

I am running Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.5.8. I am trying to get “*It worked*” for a new install. I get *Error 324* from Chrome:

```
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

When I kill the server, I get the following traceback:

```
0 errors found
June 02, 2014 - 06:39:55
Django version 1.5.8, using settings 'fed1.settings.dev'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
♥Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of     <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x19fd950>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vagrant/fed1-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
File "/home/vagrant/fed1-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 186, in run
httpd.serve_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

I read somewhere that this error had to do with Python 2.5.1 and was gone in 2.5.2. I can’t find that now. It must have been somewhere in code.djangoproject.com, but perhaps this is not the same issue.

I saw [How to 'clear' the port when restarting django runserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880239/how-to-clear-the-port-when-restarting-django-runserver) where people said the server was already running, so I tried that solution:

```
(fed1-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/fed1$ ps aux | grep -i manage
vagrant  10113  0.0  0.2  11676   940 pts/0    S+   14:57   0:00 grep --color=auto -i manage
```

And then tried bringing it to the foreground to kill but:

```
(fed1-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/fed1$ fg
bash: fg: current: no such job
```

So that is not my problem, either.

[Django - Strange behavior using static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171955/django-strange-behavior-using-static-files) has a similar error resolved with URL patterns – but I’m not there yet. I’m just trying to get ‘it worked’. Most of the people I see asking about this error have sites up and running in production already.

I looked at `socketserver.py` but I'm not advanced enough to interpret that.

Comment: If you have a new question, post it as such. Do not change your question because we helped you resolve your first one.

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about the exception, you can safely ignore it. Your server has exited already, albeit a little messily.

On shut-down, Python cleans up global names to prevent circular dependencies from holding up finalisation. It does so by rebinding them no `None`.

You were shutting down the server with a Keyboard Interrupt (CTRL-C), triggering finalisation. In the meantime, the `serve_forever` thread was still running it's socket polling loop, but the `select` global in the `SocketServer` module had already been rebound. As a result the lookup for `select.select()` fails.

If this bothers you, upgrade to Python 3.4. This version no longer sets globals to `None` (in most cases), as per [Safe Object Finalization](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-442); see [PEP 442](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).

As for your Chrome error code and your other question, **something** is already bound to the port you are trying to use for Django. That's an entirely separate issue from the exception you saw for the `select.select()` call. It could be that another piece of software is holding on to that port, something that doesn't respond to HTTP requests (leading to the Chrome error response).

See [Determining what process is bound to a port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/determining-what-process-is-bound-to-a-port) (Linux) or [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x) (Mac) to troubleshoot that issue.

Comment: I followed the link you gave for determining what process is bound to a port, ran netstat but there was nothing on either port 8000 or 8888.  I decided to try closing my VM and rebooting. This time when I ran runserver Chrome still says there is no response, but when I closed the server there was no error output from the console at all.  I guess that's good if it shows the select error is resolved, but I have no idea where to go next with the 'no response' issue.

Comment: p.s. Maybe I should add/explain that 8888 is the port vagrant forwards to.